# Losing Session in IE 8

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8, kohana

I have run into an issue where session is being dropped only in IE 8 (Works in IE 9), and it only happens after a single page is loaded.

I don't have any place in the code where i clear the session.

I'm using Kohana 2 and i have tried setting the Kohana setting:

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

I also tried setting the Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But no luck.

Is there any advice on how to debug the issue?

Comment: Check a session id cookie first

Comment: Did you open another tab before the sessions expire?

Answer (score 0):

**content="IE=edge"** is just the rendering engine of Internet Explorer, it doesn't affect session cookie at all, this means it should be fine with both IE8 & IE9 if you write your code correctly.

Please check your code how you set the session cookie name, when the value of session cookie does not match with the value on server you will fall into a situation just like session already dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by not including an htc File that was only added in IE:

```
.round4 { iecss3-border-radius: 4px; behavior: url(/assets/js/ie/ie-css3.htc); }
.round10 { iecss3-border-radius: 10px; behavior: url(/assets/js/ie/ie-css3.htc); }
.roundTop10 { iecss3-border-radius-top-left-radius: 10px; iecss3-border-radius: 10px; behavior: url(/assets/js/ie/ie-css3.htc); }
```

Although i don't see a connection between Session Loss and htc file.